Error during update - problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry
I have a ubuntu VM
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Id run apt update, apt upgrade, changed prompt=normal as I was getting develp cant upgrade to LTS
, rebooted but when I try to
sudo do-release-upgrade

I get

Error during update  A problem occurred during the update. This is
usually some sort of  network problem, please check your network
connection and retry. Maybe I am not sure that the following might be
the origin of the issue, just an idea but even when upgrade went
through but I had a message as follows
Err https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/ubuntu focal
InRelease                                             The following
signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 3F01618A51312F3F GitLab B.V.
(package repository signing key) packages@gitlab.com Fetched 23,4 kB
in 0s (0 B/s)

I updated the key with following
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -


I switched back to Prompt=lts but getting the same error

Are you sure that link is correct?  Open it in a browser & you'll see the problem I expect
